# Setting a new primary font-family with Bulma

Tags: css, bulma

I'm trying to update the variable for the primary font-family in Bulma but nothing seems to be happening. So far, what I've done is:

1. Import the initial variables and functions file.
2. Import the fonts I would like with Google Fonts
3. Set a new variable called `$family-serif: "Grandstander", serif;`
4. Update the `$family-primary` to equal the value of `$family-serif`;
5. Import the Bulma with `@import "../assets/bulma/bulma.sass";`

The source code can be found at: https://github.com/jacobcollinsdev/eponym, and I've include the code snippets below:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url('../assets/bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables.sass');
@import url('../assets/bulma/sass/utilities/functions.sass');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abhaya+Libre:wght@500;800&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Grandstander&display=swap');

$family-serif: "Grandstander", serif;
$family-primary: $family-serif;

@import "../assets/bulma/bulma.sass";
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">

    <title>Home | Eponym Mag</title>
</head>
```

I've only recently began using Bulma and think I may have gotten myself into a bit of a mess with what files I need to include etc, any insight appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but: you have to import just all you need from Bulma after setting all variables you want to customize (this is mentioned a few times in [documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/#generic-variables)).
Also, there are examples for customize with [node-sass](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/#6-add-your-own-bulma-styles),[Sass CLI](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-sass-cli/#6-add-your-own-bulma-styles) and [webpack](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-webpack/#9-add-your-own-bulma-styles).

```
@charset "utf-8";

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abhaya+Libre:wght@500;800&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Grandstander&display=swap');

$family-serif: "Grandstander", serif;
$family-primary: $family-serif;

@import "../assets/bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables.sass";
@import "../assets/bulma/sass/utilities/functions.sass";
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a bit late, I was having this same problem. I was using Rolllup JS with `--watch`(bundle running in background, watching for JS/SCSS file changes) flag. Primary was not updating no matter what I tried.

I was ready to give up when I stopped my `--watch`. Re-started Rollup and bang, primary and the rest were all updated. So I just needed to re-start my Rollup.